# Accessing Entity Framework V4 properties in a weakly typed fashion

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am trying to determine if there is a way to access entity framework entity properties in a weakly typed fashion.

Instead of accessing the description property this way: **myEntity.Description**

I would really like to access it using an indexer: **myEntity["Description"]**

I have looked at the object model.  The ObjectContext.Translate<>() method takes a DbDataReader but I have not found a way to access the DbDataReader, DataRow, etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
...Marc

Answer (score 1):

You can extend T4 template and to do it for you. You can either do it by reflection (slow, bad) or use silly (but fast) approach with `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EntityClient which streams results as an EntityDataReader which as the name suggests is an implementation of DbDataReader.